# How to build gRPC++ with OpenSSL instead of BoringSSL

Tags: c++, grpc

My project uses MySQL connector, which use OpenSSL as its dependency.
I've integrate gRPC with my project using FetchContent, with OpenSSL installed in my system. But it still use BoringSSL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add these to your CMakeList.txt

```
set(gRPC_SSL_PROVIDER package)
```

Comment: Alternatively you can add `-DgRPC_SSL_PROVIDER=package` as command-line parameter when calling `cmake`. That's the way gRPC describes for building the gRPC libs. This is the way to set additional options without modifications on sources.

Answer (score 1):

gRPC offers two ways to get its dependencies: with `add_subdirectory` ([I'm not a big fan of this way](https://www.acarg.ch/posts/cmake-deps/)), and with `find_package` (that's my favorite).

As documented [here](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L69-L71):

```py
# Providers for third-party dependencies (gRPC_*_PROVIDER properties):
# "module": build the dependency using sources from git submodule (under third_party)
# "package": use cmake's find_package functionality to locate a pre-installed dependency
```

So in order to use your own SSL library, the best way is to:

1. Make sure gRPC uses `find_package`, with `-DgRPC_SSL_PROVIDER=package`.
2. Make sure that your SSL library will be found by `find_package`. Either because it is installed system-wide, or by using `-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` to help `find_package` find it.

[Here is an example](https://github.com/acarg/cmake-deps-example-grpc) fetching and building gRPC and its dependencies from sources. Note [this line in particular](https://github.com/acarg/cmake-deps-example-grpc/blob/main/dependencies/grpc/CMakeLists.txt#L21), where gRPC is instructed to use the "package" mode.

I would advise against adding `set(gRPC_SSL_PROVIDER package)` to your CMakeLists.txt. This should not be a concern of your project's CMakeLists, hence it's better to pass it as a command (`-DgRPC_SSL_PROVIDER=package`).

Answer (score -1):

We use gRPC by compiling source code. There was an issue (application segfault) due to which it was needed to to disable boringSSL for gRPC and use OpenSSL installed on the system. There are many suggestions. But the one that worked for me is below.

```
cmake -DgRPC_SSL_PROVIDER=OpenSSL . && make && make install
```

Comment: This is wrong, see here: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L69-L71

It should be `-DgRPC_SSL_PROVIDER=module` or `-DgRPC_SSL_PROVIDER=package`